# How to know ahead of time the price of a call via Google Voice from the US to France for a `+338` number?

Tags: usa, france, financial, telephone

I live in the US and sometimes have to call French phone numbers. Numbers starting with `+331` or `+339` are landlines, but I'm facing issues with `+338` numbers: How can I know ahead of time the price of a call via Google Voice from the US to France for a `+338` number?

https://voice.google.com/rates ([mirror](https://archive.vn/JeeIR)) says:

[image]
and I'm having issue matching it with what I see on https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Num%C3%A9ro_surtax%C3%A9_en_France&oldid=175712171#La_r%C3%A9forme_des_services_%C3%A0_valeur_ajout%C3%A9e_(SVA):

[image]

For example, if I call `+3389`, how do I know whether Google Voice will bill me at 0.15 USD/minutes, 0.28 USD/minutes or 1 USD/minutes?

Comment: Have you asked Google? Google's page https://support.google.com/voice/answer/7491761?hl=en seems to address this issue.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you, yes I tried to such a solution. The page you mentioned linked to https://voice.google.com/rates, which is the one I mentioned in the question and took the screenshot from.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I'm sorry I can't help here.

Comment: And not to put a downer on this - but I don't see how this is an Expat issue (or even how it would belong with Travel). This is an issue with international calling rates from a Google service. Obviously the answer is either to get the information from Google, or to make a test call for 10 minutes, and see how much you are charged for it. I would like to vote to close this question

Comment: @ScottEarle "This is an issue with international calling rates" -> sounds like an issue for expats. "Obviously the answer is either to get the information from Google, or to make a test call for 10 minutes" -> not necessarily, e.g. if the call was made from France, we could know the price ahead of time without asking the phone operator. I don't know about international calls.

Comment: The percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere is also an issue for expats, but this is not the place to ask about it

Comment: @ScottEarle international calls are more specific to expat than oxygen is. ->  [Expatriates sucks because most questions are about Immigration](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/284/164)

Comment: I would guess this to be 0.01 (the base cost of a call to a landline) plus whatever the merchant operating the line asks. This is normally mentioned wherever the number is advertised. See the examples on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @KristvanBesien The rate is not always mentioned along with the phone number.  I agree that 0.01 USD +  whatever the merchant operating the line asks makes sense but this would contradict https://voice.google.com/rates (see screenshot the question).

Comment: I would assume that not mentioning the rate when you publish the number, or not at the start of the call foul of cunsumer protection laws in France. It does so in many countries.